# Filter array of objects by date

Tags: jquery, arrays, date

i have an array

```
0: Object
  end: "11-24-2014"
  index: 0
  start: "11-21-2014"
1: Object
  end: "12-1-2014"
  index: 1
  start: "11-28-2014
```

I need to get index of element with current date between start and end.

Any help?? Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempts, as  yet?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I do not know how to get the item based on the current date. 
the current date between the start and end dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array converting the date strings to dates and see if the current date lies between them;

```
var index = check(arry);
if (index >= 0)
    alert("found @ " + index);


function check(arry) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
        if (now >= toDate(arry[i].start) && now <= toDate(arry[i].end)) 
            return i;

    return -1;

    function toDate(str) {
        var d = str.split("-");
        return new Date(d[2], d[0] - 1, d[1]);
    }
}
```